# Drupal notifications

Tags: email, drupal, notifications

I'm struggling with notifications to display on my dashboard. This is my scenario:

1. I need to display newly registered users in user dashboard
2. I have created a content type which is only for members. The author of the node needs to get notifications about comments left in the created node, in her/his dashboard.

The notifications should not be sent via emails.
I am using Drupal 6.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the heartbeat module: http://drupal.org/project/heartbeat

It's designed to do a facebook wall type thing. But if you set up the permissions and rules correctly it can be adopted for your use case.

Just set up a rule that posts to admin heartbeat on user creation and adds to node owners heartbeat on node comment submission.